# Wrong Z-Axis movement in G-Code

Tags: z-axis, slic3r, troubleshooting, reprap

Alright so I bought a broken UP mini. There was only a defect on the board so I connected the components to a Duet 2 Wifi.
Everything is fully operational and I can manually move all axes correctly using the interface as well as homing them.

The problem is that when I try to slice a model (I am using Slic3r) and upload the G-Code the bed will be raised instead of lowered during printing.

How do I change it so the direction of the Z-Axis goes correctly?

Additional information:

- The Z endstop is at the bottom
- When homed the Z coordinate is on 0 mm
- When placing the bed under the extruder the Z coordinate is 170 mm

Comment: Did it work *before* you messed up the board?

Answer (score -1):

You could put the z endstop at the top, and flip the motor connector to make it move the other direction. This should make it home to the top near the nozzle, and then move downward during the print.

Otherwise, you'll have to tweak the firmware configuration and reflash.